# Series of binary operations in $(\mathbb{N}, *)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binary-operations, monoid

> Consider monoid $(\mathbb{N},*)$, where operation $*$ is defined as $x*y = xy + x + y$.
>
> What is the result of $1*2*3*\text{...}*25 \text{ (mod 29)}$ ?

$xy + x + y$ can be written as $(x + 1) y + x$ or $y + x (1 + y)$, but that does not seem to help in any way.

One thing I noticed is that $n * (n + 1) = \text{prime number}$. Ex: $12*13=181$; $4*5=29$.

I am still not sure how can I express $1*2*3*\text{...}*25$ in such a way that I could find the remainder of it divided by $29$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite this operation like this:

$$x*y = (x+1)(y+1)-1 $$

---

It is asociative:

$$(x*y)*z = (x*y+1)(z+1)-1 = (x+1)(y+1)(z+1)-1$$

also

$$x*(y*z) = (x+1)(y*z+1)-1 =  (x+1)(y+1)(z+1)-1$$

---

So $$1*2*3*\text{...}*25 = 2\cdot 3\cdot \text{...}\cdot 25\cdot 26 -1\text{ (mod 29)}$$
$$= 28^{-1}\cdot 27^{-1}\cdot 28!-1\text{ (mod 29)}$$
$$= (-1)\cdot (14)\cdot (-1)-1\text{ (mod 29)}$$
$$= 13\text{ (mod 29)}$$

Comment: It took me awhile to figure out how you wrote $x*y$ as $(x+1)(y+1)-1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rename your elements: Instead of $1$ say $2'$, instead of $2$ say $3'$, and so on. Try to figure out what the rule for $x'*y'$ is. For instance,
$$
2'*2'=1*1=3=4'\\
2'*3'=1*2=5=6'\\
3'*3'=2*2=8=9'
$$